# Where are my line numbers?

Tags: emacs

Running Emacs 24 (Mac OS). I enabled `line-number-mode` via `M-x`, but I'm still not seeing any line numbers? What's up? Do I need to edit my `.emacs` file too?

Thanks.

Comment: Your line numbers should be in the [mode line](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLine).

Comment: They appear to be there, but I was hoping to get them on the right hand side of my screen. I guess I'm going about it incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `linum-mode`.

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you.